# How to query environment variable from powershell

Tags: powershell

I want the below environment variable to be queried in remote server if (($ImageName -like "*devel*") -or ($ImageName -like "*hosted*")) and I want to create a condition that if below variable with below variable value found on server then "ADE instalation is success" else " ADE instalation is failed"

```
variable name :ADE_INFRA

variable value : \\scavere01-zfs.us.oim.com\ade_infra


variable name :ADE_PACKAGES

variable value : \\scavere01-zfs.us.oim.com\packages\windows
```

I have created script like below, but the script dont give any output. I am not sure whether this is the correct methord to call and read system variables. Can any one help ?

```
if (($ImageName -like "*devel*") -or ($ImageName -like "*hosted*"))

{

$env= (gci env:*).GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | Out-String

if (ADE_INFRA -eq "\\scavere01-zfs.us.oim.com\ade_infra" -And ADE_PACKAGES -eq "\\scavere01-zfs.us.oim.com\packages\windows")

        {

        $ADE = "ADE Installation Success"

        echo "ADE = ADE Installation Success"

        }

        if (ADE_INFRA -eq $null -And ADE_PACKAGES -eq $null)

        {

        $ADE = "ADE Installation Failed"


        echo "ADE = ADE Installation Failed"
        }
}
```

Comment: Look at `Invoke-Command` and `gci env:`

Comment: I read it over and over, again and again, but can't figure out what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access Environment Variable from Remote Server with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845488/cant-access-environment-variable-from-remote-server-with-powershell)

Comment: the thing is I am writing a script where which ever machine image name is like "devel" or "hosted" ,then the script should check the remote server has the above environment variable. if they found with the above value the "ADE check is successful" and if didn't find then "ADE check is failed"

Comment: I've withdrawn my duplicate flag as OP has added their own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the issues you were having with your code:

```
if (($ImageName -like "*devel*") -or ($ImageName -like "*hosted*"))
{
    $ADE_INFRA = (gci env:ADE_INFRA).value
    $ADE_PACKAGES = (gci env:ADE_PACKAGES).value

    if ($ADE_INFRA -eq "\\scavere01-zfs.us.oim.com\ade_infra" -And $ADE_PACKAGES -eq "\\scavere01-zfs.us.oim.com\packages\windows")
    {
        $ADE = "ADE Installation Success"
    }
    else
    {
        $ADE = "ADE Installation Failed"
    }

    Write-Host "ADE = $ADE"
}
```